# How do I remove Windows 8 to install Ubuntu, while retaining the data in my other drives?

Tags: system-installation, uninstall

I have windows in my C: drive.The whole C drive I can afford to lose. However, I would not like to lose my music, video clips and other such data in dives D, E and F. How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: One thing that will be important to know is if the other drives are physically separate drives, or just partitions on a single drive.  I personally would not try to install a new operating system without making a backup of what I consider to be my essential data.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred version is to first run live disk and use [gparted](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html).
Then I remove the disk/partition which I don't need and format it to ext4 for use with ubuntu system.
Plus from the live cd you can see which is the correct drive for the partition/disk you want to remove and browse the drive for triple checking.